# Vim highlight static variables

Tags: java, vim, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to get Vim highlight in some manner, **static variables** in a Java source file?
Script, configuration, anything?
I've searched for a while and think it's not possible, please prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaBrowser plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=588) outlines static methods and fields in a side bar, like the popular *taglist* plugin. It relies on *Exuberant Ctags* to parse the Java source code and create a tags database of function prototypes, which it then parses for the word `static` (as ctags doesn't explicitly call this out).

The [underlinetag plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3494) uses the tag database to define syntax highlighting for all entries in the tag database.

If you implement a combination of both plugins, you'd achieve your goal. (There are also other plugins like [easytags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114), which offers automatic tag update and highlighting in one plugin.) Unfortunately, I think this is not just a matter of configuration; you'd actually have to dive in, understand how the plugins work, and modify the plugin logic to filter for and apply to static members only.

Comment: Interesting, could be a spare time project. Thanks.